# 8-dimensional module for S4 over a field of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, characters

I'm trying to prove that an 8-dimensional module for S4 over a field of complex numbers has a 2 dimensional submodule, I know that The character table says every irreducible representation of S_4 has dimension 1, 2, or 3.

finite dimensional representation of S_4 is a direct sum of irreducible.so I'm trying to consider all possible ways of writing 8 as a sum of 1, 2, and 3,  but I'm stucking, I'll be thankful for help to finish

Comment: You cant write 8 as a sum of 3's and at most one 1. So you must have 2 or two 1s -- both give you the submodule.

Comment: ‘A’ field of complex  numbers? What are the others?

Comment: I cant write 8 as  a sum of submodules 3 and 3 and 1 and 1 ? @ahulpke

Comment: @laim Of course you can. But that is two 1's that together give you a 2. You cannot with zero or one 1.

Comment: thank you ! @ahulpke